# Creating an app with multiple weblink buttons

Tags: android, button

I'm a new coder trying to figure out where I've gone wrong. My intent is to make an app with multiple buttons that each link to different websites. I've been using code from the web but am still not sure why it won't compile when I try adding uri.parse and am racking my brains looking for a solution.
So now I'm starting with a baseline example and trying to reverse engineer it to understand. I'm wanting the buttons to lead to a website instead of setting text. I've tried multiple solutions but none are working and I'm guessing you guys could answer this in your sleep. Thanks!

Update figured it out guys thanks!
Working java below

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
TextView tvOut;
Button btnOk;
Button btnCancel;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // find View-elements
    tvOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOut);
    btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

    // assign listeners to buttons
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // define the button that invoked the listener by id
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnOk:
        // ОК button// Open Website
        Intent intent;

        try {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/yourPage"));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception Caught", e.toString());
        }

        break;
        case R.id.btnCancel:
        // Cancel button
        Intent intent2;

        try {
            intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/yourPage"));
            intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception Caught", e.toString());
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: are you facing any error ?

Comment: I literally just figured it out after I posted it. I'll leave the example here for anyone else asking the same question.

Comment: You can post your working solution as an answer to your own question and accept it. Do NOT put the working code into your question; instead leave the non-working code there, so others can see what was wrong and what is the solution.

Comment: Understood, first post sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep the context of the webpage(s) within your app, you'll need to add a webview in your activity layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
       <WebView
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:id="@+id/webView"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

then add in onCreate:

```
          final WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
          webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

you'll need to add this to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

this way you can keep things in control.. otherwise, you'll need to do it with an Intent.  simple example and docs for that are here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html